# Unable to create directory in android using cordova-plugin-file

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to create a directory in phone storage using this code and this plugin [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/).

```
function createDirectory(fileSystem){
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
    var folderName = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'SomeFolder/';
    console.log(folderName);

    directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(parent){
        console.log(parent);
    }, function(err){
        console.log('Error while creating directory.',err)
    })
}
```

But it throws this err :

```
`Error while creating directory. FileError {code: 5}`
```

How to solve this error and create a directory in root of phone storage ?

The documentation only shows that this error `code : 5` means `ENCODING_ERR`

Comment: `SomeFolder/` indicates a path, instead use `SomeFolder` to declare a folder name…

Comment: I tried this also.. but the error remains the same

Comment: Did you find a solution?